# Centos7 nginx install not responding

Tags: nginx, centos7

Have install Centos7 DVD version on VBOX.  Installed nginx and nginx -t is successful.  Can ping from desktop but times out trying to browse by IP address.  Using standard /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf .  Have set setenforce Permissive

No entries in /var/log/nginx/error.log  or access.log

Have installed MS-SQL ODBC driver and can see remote SQL Server.

TIA

Comment: What about `firewall`, is it on?

Comment: ARRrrgggg!  Thanks!    If you make that an answer I'll vote it best.

Comment: I just answered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your firewall)

either configure it properly (don't forget to `service iptables save` to save it):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

or disable if you don't need it:

```
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]# service iptables stop && chkconfig iptables off
iptables: Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter          [  OK  ]
iptables: Flushing firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
iptables: Unloading modules:                               [  OK  ]
[root@wcmisdlin02 ~]#
```

Comment: Don't disable your firewall. Just add a rule to allow HTTP traffic.
/etc/sysconfig/iptables => -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 4):

CentOS 7 is using firewalld now.

Example:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent
```

reload rules:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

btw: maybe you want to autostart nginx service on boot:

```
# systemctl enable nginx
```